# concatenating rows from two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Given the below two data frames

```
key  name1  name2  name3
 k1    a       b      c
 k2    c       d      s



key  name4  name5  name6
 k1    t      f      h
 k2    v      s      u
```

how do I concatenate both data frames into 1, using the key column as reference, so it looks like:

```
key  name1  name2  name3  key  name4  name5  name6
 k1    a      b      c     k1    t      f      h
 k2    c      d      s     k2    v      s      u
```

Comment: This operation is called a join or merge. There is a function `merge`.

Comment: With `merge`, you can further specify the `by` argument to refer to a column both data frames have. In your above example, you would set `by = "key"`

Answer (score 2):

Using merge you can merge the data frame, in this case you have two df and you want to merge

```
> df1
  key name1 name2 name3
1  k1     a     b     c
2  k2     c     d     s
> df2
  key name4 name5 name6
1  k1     t     f     h
2  k2     v     s     u
> df3 <-merge(df1,df2,by="key")
> df3
  key name1 name2 name3 name4 name5 name6
1  k1     a     b     c     t     f     h
2  k2     c     d     s     v     s     u
>
```

for more details you can type ?merge in your R console

Comment: @gung thank you for your comment, I already edit my answer

Comment: This sounds like the right answer, but if you want to merge row by row and not the entire data frame in one shot. What would be the solution?

Comment: The solution would be not to do that.

Comment: @user1375640 actually i am not understand wht you mean to merge row by row, but if you want the data looks like example that you give you can use cbind function for combine two data frame by columns.
`df3 = cbind(df1,df2)`